# Get Specific elements from HTML in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, nsstring

how can i get specific elements from html page
if i have this nsstring with this value

```
<body style="background-color: 3399CC;font-size: 200.5%;font-family:monospace;font-style:oblique;">


<div id="1" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>

<div id="2" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>
```

I want to clear everything except div with id number 2 to be like this

```
 </div>

<div id="2" align="center" style="padding-top: 10%;" >
 <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">fawazapp</h1>
 <p style="color: #C0C0C0;"> bbb</p>
 <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">aaaaaaaaa</p>

 </div>
```

Comment: Use a HTML parser. This seems to be a good introduction: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios.

Comment: @MartinR that article under the link looks a bit complicated...

Comment: You could use javascript if you have loaded the html into a web view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIWebView` has a method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` so if you have (or create) some javascript to navigate / manipulate / interrogate the page contents you can run it to obtain the result.