# Loading specific elements from webpages in xCode

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, webview

So my question is quite simple but I have no idea where to begin. I'm trying to make an app in xCode for OSX that will load up specific parts from webpages. The problem is whenever I use the built-in web navigator the entire page loads up.

I looked up for several relative questions on Stackoverflow and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522181/get-specific-elements-from-html-in-uiwebview) but I can't really understand the answer given as it only explains how I can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to "have (or create) some javascript to navigate / manipulate / interrogate the page contents" according to Wain.

Also I want the user to be able to interact with the element loaded, meaning it will refresh over time or whenever active.

Important note: I'm using third-party websites.
Also I'm not asking for code, more like some tutorial/documentation on how to achieve what I'm looking for. Furthermore, I have no example code to offer, as this is a pre-development phase.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the UIWebView won't allow you to do this. You can use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) to load the web page into an NSData object, then [convert that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring) to an NSString object. You can then extract just the parts you want from the string, and do what you like with them. You could build a new HTML page in memory to display in a UIWebView, or you could build an attributed string to display in a UITextView.